# Serial port access denied, even though in dialout group

Tags: 16.04, usb, permissions, tty

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

I am having issues using USB to serial adapters. Up until a couple of moths ago, I was able to use putty just fine to connect to the ports (I'm in the dialout group). Now I get permission denied unless I run putty with `sudo`.

I did also discover today if I run `newgrp dialout` in a terminal, I can run putty just fine from that session.

This has happened on all of the machines in our office so some sort of update caused the issue.

Anyone have any clues? I've searched a lot and the basic answer is add yourself to dialout which does not apply here since I was in dialout and it was working.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you verify you're actually in the group by running `id` and check your groups that you're actually in, and that `dialout` is actually in that list? (Before running newgrp)

Comment: Yes groups jbarnes
jbarnes : systemd-journal tty dialout sudo wireshark vboxusers ics leng access zadmin rt1000 ue9000 rndit gccs

Comment: I now know what is causing the issue, just need to get the right fix. It is the issue being discussed here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458194/missing-groups-at-each-startup/458523#458523